# boost::compute, passing pointer to a closure

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, closures, boost-compute

Good evening! I am writing a high-performance application and trying to use boost to speed up complex computations.

The essence of my question: is there a way to pass an external pointer to array (like `float4_ *`) to a `BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE`?
I'd like to get something like:

```
float4_ *normals = new float4_[NORMALS_NO];
BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE(void, evalNormals, (int4_ indices), (normals), {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have finally found out how to implement the declared options.
First thing to do is to pass `boost::compute::detail::device_ptr<float4_>` instance to the function. Next we should declare a typename generator for `OpenCL backend` and `operator<<` to write pointer information into `meta_kernel` instance, which is being used in a hidden way in closure definition. So, the code:

1) Passing `device_ptr` instance

```
...
#include <boost/compute/detail/device_ptr.hpp>
...
float4_ *normalsData = new float4_[NORMALS_NO];
device_ptr<float4_> normalsDataDP = normalsData;
...
BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE(void, evalNormals, (int4_ indices), (normalsDataDP), {
    ...
});
...
```

2) Implement typename generator:

```
...
namespace boost {
    namespace compute {
        template<>
        inline const char *type_name<detail::device_ptr<float4_>>()
        {
            return "__global float4 *";
        }
    }
}
...
```

3) Implement `operator<<`

```
...
namespace boost {
    namespace compute {
        namespace detail {
            meta_kernel &operator<<(meta_kernel &kern, 
                                    const device_ptr<float4_> &ptr)
            {
                std::string nodes_info = kern.get_buffer_identifier<float4_>(ptr.get_buffer());
                kern << kern.var<float4_ *>(nodes_info);
                return kern;
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This answer is old but I would be interested in a full example. I dont see a ctor or assignment operator for `device_ptr` that takes a raw pointer, only a buffer. How does that work? Do I need a `typename generator` and  `operator<<` for every pointers that I want to capture in the closure?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE` is slightly sparse as reported [here](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/issues/361) by the library author, but [some test cases](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/test/test_closure.cpp) show how to capture `vector`s and `array`s. It actually works transparently, the same than with scalar.

For instance, capturing `vec`:

```cpp
int data[] = {6, 7, 8, 9};
compute::vector<int> vec(data, data + 4, queue);

BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE(int, get_vec, (int i), (vec), { return vec[i]; });

// run using a counting iterator to copy from vec to output
compute::vector<int> output(4, context);
compute::transform(
    compute::make_counting_iterator(0),
    compute::make_counting_iterator(4),
    output.begin(),
    get_vec,
    queue);
CHECK_RANGE_EQUAL(int, 4, output, (6, 7, 8, 9));
```